# What are mountpoints, and which one should I pick?

Tags: installation, mountpoint

When a Ubuntu is fresh installed an option called Mount Point is shown in Advanced Install.On clicking it i get a dropdown list with options:

```
/
/home
/bin
swap
```

etc

What exactly are they? and which one is best suited for 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `mountpoint` defines where in the filesystem that particular drive is mounted.

The root of the filesystem is always `/` - and you must always have one. Everything lives in here.

You can then (optionally) add other mountpoints to segregate your data, for instance `/home` contains all your user-specific files. So you might have another bigger hard drive that you want all your user files on if you're storing lots of photos in your home directory.

However, the most basic use-case is to simply start with one drive and mount it at `/`, which is likely what you want for now.

The only special case is `swap`, which is not a mountpoint in the normal filesystem, but is used as additional memory (on disk) - Windows calls it a pagefile.